# swagger_doc.json returns wrong swagger doc urls

Tags: ruby-on-rails, swagger, swagger-ui

My https://x.y/api/swagger_doc.json returns this:

```
{"apiVersion":"0.1","swaggerVersion":"1.2","produces":["application/xml","application/json","application/vnd.api+json","text/plain"],"apis":[{"path":"/ping.{format}","description":"Operations about pings"},{"path":"/ping_dev.{format}"
```

Notice that the path is pointing to the /ping.{format} It should point to /swagger_doc/ping.json. Because of this the swagger ui gives me this error:

```
Unable to read api 'friends' from path https://x.y:443/api/ping.json
```

I can access manually the ping.json form https://x.y:443/api/swagger_doc/ping.json.
The content is what would be needed by swagger ui:

```
{"apiVersion":"0.1","swaggerVersion":"1.2","resourcePath":"/ping","produces":["application/xml","application/json","application/vnd.api+json","text/plain"],"apis":[{"path":"/api/ping.{format}","operations":[{"notes":"","summary":"Returns pong.","nickname":"GET-api-ping---format-","method":"GET","parameters":[],"type":"void"}]}],"basePath":"http://local.dime.com:3000"}
```

Any idea would be appreciated to solve this mystery:

Answer (score 0):

Huh.. That was a tough one.

It was a grape-swagger bug:

in grape-swagger (0.7.2)

```
:path => "#{url_base}/#{local_route}#{url_format}",
```

in grape-swagger (0.8.0)

```
path: "/#{local_route}#{url_format}",
```